# Not able to use a custom theme in Angular 4

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2

I'm trying to use my custom theme in my angular project. It's not working as expected, I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/custom_theme.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/theming' in '/Users/mathiasschrooten/Downloads/skylux-admin/src'
```

My styles.css file:

```
@import "custom_theme.scss"

.mat-tab-label {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

My custom_theme.scss file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-orange);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-orange, A200, A100, A400);

$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-
accent, $candy-app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

.angular-cli.json

```
      "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "custom_theme.scss"
  ],
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MathijsSegers I executed 'npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk' and 'npm install --save @angular/animations'. Is there anything else I should import? According to the docs that should be all, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove the `@import "custom_theme.scss"` from your `styles.css`. Since you have added the `custom_theme.scss` to your `angular-cli.json` (or `angular.json` for v6+) the import is not required.

After editing the `angular.json` file, **you will need to run `ng-serve` again.**

as per the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme):

> If you are using the Angular CLI, support for compiling Sass to css is
>   built-in; you only have to add a new entry to the "styles" list in
>   angular-cli.json pointing to the theme file (e.g.,
>   unicorn-app-theme.scss).

Comment: No more errors but seems like Angular doesn't recognise any theme (no colors visible whatsoever and components don't work as expected)

Comment: Try close the server and rebuild using `ng-serve`

Comment: thanks bro, cant believe that restarting the server did the trick

Comment: Please add restarting the server as the correct answer! :-)