# Error importing angular material 6 custom theme in styles.css

Tags: angular, postcss-import, css-import, angular-material-6

I created a custom theme using Angular Material 6. When I import the theme in styles.css I get the error:

> ./src/styles.css
>   (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./src/styles.css)
>   Module build failed: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/theming'
>   in 'C:\Users\D3L1ghT\Documents\PROJECTS\social-network\techhub\src'

Here is my code for my-theme.scss:

```
@import "~@angular/material/theming";

@include mat-core();

$my-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-custom-blue, 400);
$my-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-custom-blue, A100, A100, A400);

$my-theme: mat-light-theme($my-theme-primary, $my-theme-accent);

$primary-color: map_get($my-theme-primary, 400);
$secondary-color: map_get($my-theme-accent, 500);

@include angular-material-theme($my-theme);
```

Here is the code for styles.css:

```
/* @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; */
@import url("./my-theme.scss");
```

This is a screenshot of angular.json: [angular.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r29JD.png)

Comment: Why you `input` in angular.JSON file while importing file?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47789987/3055401)

Answer (score 2):

You should not add your `theme.scss` file inside the css file.

**Follow these steps:**

1. (Optional) Delete default theme in file `src/styles.css`:

   ```
   @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/the-default-theme.css';
   ```
2. Create a file `theme.scss` inside `src` folder.
3. Open file `angular.json` (or `angular-cli.json`) inside your root folder
4. Add your theme `"src/theme.scss"` into the `styles` array:

   ```
   "projects": {
     "your-app": {
       ...
       "architect": {
         "build": {
           ...
           "options": {
             ...
             "styles": [
               "src/styles.css",
               "src/theme.scss"
             ],
           },
         },
       },
     },
   }
   ```
5. Restart the app.

**Further links:**

- [Theming Guideline from material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by uninstalling my current nodejs and installing the latest version 8.11.3 and everything worked fine. I didn't have to import in styles.css anymore as learnt from the link @Und3rTow posted. Also, I no longer used input in angular.json @pardeep-jain. Thanks guys